# Could someone explain this Paperclip syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I haven't worked with Paperclip before, but recently I have gotten a big file with some Paperclip syntax in it. I read the docs at http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip but some parts are not very clear to me.

- What is an `io_adapter` and what is it used for?
- What does the "r" mean in `File.open(user.file.path, "r")`, what is it used for and what is that part called? I don't think it's a variable of some sort since it doesn't appear at any other places.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"io" - Ruby IO http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html

"r" means "read" http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode

Comment: Thanks, this explains it very well.